# How to construct a class from a pack in C++?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

I am trying to initialize a class with a pack passed as an argument to my function. Here is what I got so far:

```cpp
struct Vec3
{
    float x, y, z;
};

template<typename _Ty, typename... Args>
__forceinline _Ty construct_class(Args&&... arguments)
{
    return _Ty(arguments...);
}

// here I am trying to construct a Vec3 by calling construct_class
Vec3 vec = construct_class<Vec3>(10.f, 20.f, 30.f);
```

Unfortunately I get the following compiler error in visual studio: `C2440 '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to '_Ty'`

I have seen people doing this:

```cpp
template<typename _Ty, typename... Args>
__forceinline _Ty construct_class(Args&&... arguments)
{
    return _Ty(std::forward<Args>(arguments)...);
}
```

But this also doesn't work for me, I get the exact same compiler error as before.

So my question is how should I use the pack/intializer list inside construct_class to construct the `_Ty` class (in this case `Vec3`)? I am not familiar with packs in C++.

Comment: Use brackets: `_Ty{std::forward<Args>(arguments)...};` or just `return {std::forward<Args>(arguments)...};`

Comment: the tag `pack` doesn't apply here, maybe variadic templates and perfect forwarding

Comment: `_TY` name is reserved to the language implementation. Don't use it as a template parameter.

Comment: Identifiers starting with `_` followed by an uppercase letter are reserved for the compiler/standard library. `_Ty(<expression>)` doesn't consider aggregate initialization though, so it fails, since there is no suitable constructor taking the arguments passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace `return _Ty(arguments...)` with `return _Ty{arguments...}` as shown below:

```
//---------------v--------------------- v----->removed the underscore
template<typename Ty, typename... Args>  Ty construct_class(Args&&... arguments)
{
//-----------v------------v------------------->used curly braces instead of parenthesis
    return Ty{arguments...};
}
```

[Working Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/hFhzuIdRY)

---

Also, note that the given program will [work](https://wandbox.org/permlink/b5f7vmtl3z2hsbA3) with C++20 without having to use curly braces.

---

Also, [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) might come in handy when using leading underscore for names.

Comment: I suggest mentioning that this would work in C++20.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Added a note.  Though for some reason even with C++20, it doesn't compile [here](https://onlinegdb.com/GHgEhViOs). Maybe there is something wrong with the compiler(or option/flag) they're using. It works as expected [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/b5f7vmtl3z2hsbA3) though.